# How to restart windows server 2003 automatically

Tags: windows

How can I restart my Windows 2003 server at a specific interval of time automatically twice a day with a batch file?

Or is there a simpler option than a batch file?

Comment: Run a scheduled task?

Comment: If you *have* to restart a server regularly, you have deeper problems I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Batch file (.BAT) as:

```
shutdown /f /r /t 10
```

Setup a scheduled task to run that batch file at the days/times you require.